# AngularJS: prevent a 404 error in img src attribute

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404

I want to load the thumbnail of video

```
<img src="http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/{{video.id}}">
```

But until AngularJS is loaded, I get a 404 error

> GET http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/%7B%7Bvideo.id%7D%7D
>   404 (Not Found)

It's not a big deal, but I would like to solve it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should be using `ng-src` or the image url will be resolved literally. 
a video like `http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/4` does exist, but not the literal string `http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/{{video.id}}`

I made a [jsfiddle demonstrating the img ng-src](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2MVt/2/) behaviour. You can see with the network tab in Firebug that you don't get a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know ng-src.